# Гибернация приложений

Tags: windows

Существует ли функционал позволяющий замораживать приложение перенося все данные из оперативной памяти на жесткий диск? Тем самым освободив оперативную память для другого приложения и сохранив сеанс замороженного приложения.

Comment: Этот функционал встроен в любую современную операционную систему (в том числе Windows), работает автоматически и не требует никаких действий с вашей стороны, называется подкачка

Comment: Эм... `docker`?

Comment: @andreymal а как заставить перевести в подкачку программу? Просто настроить подкачку на приложения, свернуть ненужное приложение и запустить нужное? Ничего больше делать не нужно?

Comment: Просто запустите нужное, и ненужное само в подкачку уйдёт, если понадобится

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Comment: программа даже не целиком уйдёт, а страницы по 4 килобайта не используемые будут уходит в paging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Программа Process Hacker 2
правой кнопкой на процесс Suspend (Приостановить).